# react native image picker send to spring boot error

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, react-native

const loadLibrary = useCallback(async () => {
launchImageLibrary(
{
mediaType: 'photo',
},
response => {
if (response?.errorCode) {
console.log('LaunchImageLibrary Error: ', response.errorMessage);
} else {
console.log('response=', response.assets[0]);

```
      const formData = new FormData();

      formData.append('image', {
        name: response.assets[0].fileName, // require, file name
        uri: response.assets[0].uri, // require, file absoluete path
        type: response.assets[0].type, // options, if none, will get mimetype from `filepath` extension
      });
      console.log('formData=', formData);
      axios
        .post('/users', formData)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      // );
    }
  },
);
```

}, [userInfo]);

spring code ---
@PostMapping(value="/api/v1/users")
public String createUser(
@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image) {
System.out.println(image);
return "";
}

-error--
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request

how to deal with?
Previously, this code worked well.

Answer (score 0):

try this and let me know

```
const formData = new FormData();
    formdata.append("image", {type: 'image/jpg', uri:response.assets[0], name:response.assets[0]});

      console.log('formData=', formData);
      axios
        .post('/users', formData)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      // );
    }
  },
);
```